# How to share variables between feature runs in Karate?

Tags: karate

I have an application that creates a token once by using `karate.callSingle()` in my `karate-config` file.

This token however expires after some time, so I might need to recreate it after some tests.

My plan would be to set the time of creation in a variable that can be shared in subsequent iterations of the `karate-config` file, so that I can recreate the token if the time difference is big enough.

Is there a way in Karate in which I can set a variable in the `karate-config` that can be shared in subsequent iterations ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I followed Peter Thomas' advice and used Java by "caching" properties between features. Here's my implementation :

```
var tokenRefreshTimeInMinutes = 5;
var myToken = {};
var KarateCache = Java.type('KarateCache');
var lastRefreshTime = KarateCache.get('lastRefreshTime');

if (!lastRefreshTime || differenceInMinutes(new Date(lastRefreshTime), new Date()) >= tokenRefreshTimeInMinutes) {
    myToken = karate.call('theFileRefreshingTheToken');
    KarateCache.add('lastRefreshTime', new Date().toUTCString());
    KarateCache.add('myToken', JSON.stringify(myToken));
} else {
    myToken = JSON.parse(KarateCache.get('myToken'));
}
```

with this simple KarateCache Java class

```
private static final Map<String, String> KARATE_CACHE = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public static void add(String key, String value) {
    KARATE_CACHE.put(key, value);
}

public static String get(String key) {
    return KARATE_CACHE.get(key);
}
```

Comment: yep ! make sure you mark this answer as accepted once the time-limit is up. I was thinking all the above logic could have been written as one static method (and using a static variable maybe with `synchronize`) so you just do `Java.type('KarateCache').getToken()` - BTW I don't recommend JSON.parse at all, you normally never need it in Karate - refer type conversion: https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion

Comment: As always, thanks a lot for your quick answers :) I'll follow your advice for the `JSON.parse()`. I would also prefer to have all that logic in java, but unfortunately I don't think I can here because the refresh logic is in a feature file which, according to my knowledge of Karate, can only be called programatically in a js or feature file.

Comment: oh you are right since you need to make some HTTP requests. for the record, karate has a Java API to call a feature (with params / variables set) and get results out as a hashmap, but maybe that would be overkill: https://github.com/intuit/karate#java-api

Answer (score 1):

Are you storing the result of `callSingle()` to a variable? Like:

```
var tokenResult = karate.callSingle('createToken.feature', config);
```

If you save the expiration time to a variable `expirationTime` inside `createToken.feature`, you can access it in `karate-config.js` as `tokenResult.expirationTime`.

Comment: that's a great solution. I would add that for these cases I would consider using Java. you can put any complex logic, and you can also model the Java class as a singleton.

Comment: I don't think it's a working solution, because this `tokenResult.expirationTime` is cached by `callSingle` and cannot be changed when the token is refreshed.