# Token management in Karate parallel execution

Tags: karate, junit5

Scenario : All the endpoints in my API test need authentication and hence authorization header needs to be passed. I have `Authentication.feature` file where I read refresh token from a file, generate new access token, write the new refresh token back to the file. After running each scenario, I need to update the refresh token back to the file and it will be consumed by next feature. `Authentication.feature` file is called from `karate-config.js` file and authentication header is set as shown below

```
var response = karate.call('classpath:Test/features/Authentication.feature',config).response;
var token = response.access_token
karate.configure('headers',{Authorization: 'Bearer '+token});
```

Everything till now is working fine, but when I use `junit5` parallel runner, it causes issues with the authentication token. Not the latest refresh token is written to the file. I tried by making the file read/write part synchronized, but it does not solve the problem. Also I tried `@parallel=false` annotation in Authentication.feature, still no luck. How can I make my test run parallel at the same time it correctly update the file with latest refresh token

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to do this is to use `karate.callSingle()` - please read about it if you haven't already: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#hooks

Note that this code example below is JS in `karate-config.js`:

```
var result = karate.callSingle('classpath:some/package/my.feature');
```

Also see this answer for some other ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53516885/143475